# plone/jquery - When a form is opened as a popup overlay, what is causing javascript to not work?

Tags: jquery, plone

I have a dexterity content type that includes the behavior plone.app.event.dx.behaviors.IEventBasic.

In a browserview page, I have a form that opens when a link is clicked, using jquery in a javascript file in my resources folder:

```
jquery(function($){

   ....
   $(".openCT").prepOverlay(
         {
             subtype: 'ajax',
             filter: '#content>*',
             formselector: '#content-core > form',
             noform: 'reload',
             closeselector: '[name="form.buttons.cancel"]',
         }
     );
    ....     
});
```

The form opens, but anything jquery/javascript related does not work.
In particular the whole_day does not work as the "time components" that show hour and minutes will not hide when whole_day is set to True.  Is there something I need to include so that jquery/javascript will work in a popup overlay?

Edit:
My form is a dexterity.AddForm:

```
class Add(dexterity.AddForm):
    grok.name('my.product.tevent')

    def updateWidgets(self):
        super(Add,self).updateWidgets()
        if 'a_param' in self.request.form.keys():

            #set default value of start date, which is a tuple built from data obtained from a_param
            self.widgets['IEventBasic.start'].value = (a_year,a_month,a_day,an_hour,a_min,a_timezone)
            #start-> hour,min are 0,0 / end -> hour, min are 23,59
```

Comment: Crank up the Javascript console in your browser and look for error messages. Odds are that some JS error aborted the load before your code was even reached.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no error messagss showing in the console.  I tried this with FireFox, Chromium, and Web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Anyone looking at this, please note that this answer is for Plone 4.3.x. Popups are handled differently in Plone 5+.*

Ajax overlays are inserted into the DOM when the link or button is clicked. The new elements thus do not have any jQuery events attached to them (unless the jQuery events were added with 'live' mechanisms which reattach events every time the DOM is changed).

So, you need to re-run any JS initialization code to attach events to the new DOM elements. You can do that by adding an onLoad event to the overlay configuration:

```
$(".openCT").prepOverlay({
    subtype: 'ajax',
    ...
    config: {
        onLoad: function () {
            // js code to attach events to new DOM elements
    }}
...
});
```

This event fires after the overlay has been loaded and displayed. Thus, the new elements are available in the DOM. The items that may go in "config" are documented in the [jQueryTools docs](http://jquerytools.github.io/documentation/overlay/index.html).

Comment: Sorry for my late response.  Thank you.  This does solve issues with my own functions.  I have to find a way to attach the jquery that IEventBasic has, but thank you for the step in the right direction.

Comment: I have another problem similar to this, but I'm not sure if it would be appropriate to ask a new question.  I have a validator defined in my file (a validator.SimpleFieldValidator) and the jQuery I placed in onLoad, such as changing the values in the minutes field from 0-59 to 0 and 30, breaks when the user clicks the submit button with invalid input.  By breaks, I mean the minute field is back to 0-59.  The validator still works though.  Oddly clicking off the field as opposed to clicking the submit button doesn't break the jquery when it validates as its supposed to.